# Scroll to anchor when Component is fully rendered in React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onload

This a (very) simplified version of my component:

```
export const DynamicComponent: FC<DynamicComponentProps> = (props) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
  const [isSticked, setIsSticked] = useState(false);
  const parentSticked = useContext(StickyContext);
  const [overridedStyles, setOverridedStyles] = useState(props.styles ?? {});
  const [overridedArgs, setOverridedArgs] = useState(props.args ?? {});
  const { config } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const data = useContext(DataContext);
  const [state, setState] = useContext(StateContext);

  const mountComponent = useMemo(() => {
    if (typeof props.mount === "undefined") return true;
    if (typeof props.mount === "boolean") return props.mount;
    if (typeof props.mount === "number") return props.mount === 1;
    if (typeof props.mount === "string") {
      let mount = stateParser.parse(props.mount, state) as unknown;
      return mount == true;
    }
    return false;
  }, [state, props.mount]);



  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const anchorHash = location.hash;
      if (
        anchorHash &&
        document &&
        document.querySelector(anchorHash) &&
        !document
          .querySelector(anchorHash)
          ?.classList.contains("already-scrolled")
      ) {
        document?.querySelector(anchorHash)?.scrollIntoView();
        document?.querySelector(anchorHash)?.classList.add("already-scrolled");
      }
    }, 50);
  }, []);

  let output = mountComponent ? (
    <StickyContext.Provider value={{ sticked: isSticked }}>
      <StyledDynamicComponent
        {...props}
        ref={ref}
        isSticked={applyStickedStyles}
        args={overridedArgs}
        styles={overridedStyles}
      />
    </StickyContext.Provider>
  ) : null;

  return output;
};
```

The code inside the useLayoutEffect won't run correctly without the setTimeout because the component is not fully rendered and `document?.querySelector(anchorHash)` does not exist yet..

Tried with a `window.onload` but the code inside it will never run..

Is there a way to prevent using that horrendous setTimeout?

Also please note that the anchor or the anchored element are optional so I don't know how to use callaback refs

Comment: This is what [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) are for

Comment: remember that this is using a functional component so it has not `componentDidMount`.. how would you do it in this case?

Comment: callback refs have nothing to do with `componentDidMount`. You pass a function as a ref to a component. The component that receives the callback ref calls the function when it has something of interest for you. You don't even need to use a `ref` actually, you can just pass in a `callThisWhenYouHaveADomNode` prop. Generally, if you find yourself calling `querySelector` in react, you should tread with extra caution and are most likely (but not always) doing something "un-reactlike" - i.e. hard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `document.querySelector` and don't check class names, if you can use states for it.

You don't need `setTimeout` at all, as `useEffect` and `useEffectLayout` are more or less the same as `componentDidMount`:

> If you’re migrating code from a class component, note useLayoutEffect fires in the same phase as componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate. However, we recommend starting with useEffect first and only trying useLayoutEffect if that causes a problem. [useLayoutEffect-Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect)

I tried to reduce your samle a little bit more and made it debuggable in the codesandbox (hopefully keeping your logic in tact).

[image: Edit React PlayGround (forked)]

But the most important part would be the following:

```
const ref = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref.current || !document) {
      return;
    }

    // check if a hash is provided
    // possible todo: is the current element id the same as the provided location hash id
    if(!location.hash) {
      return true;
    }

    // check if we've scrolled already
    if(scrolled) {
      return;
    }

    ref.current.scrollIntoView();

    console.log("scroll to view", ref);
    setScrolled(true);
}, [ref, location, scrolled]);
```

Your component will then be rendered  each time, the `ref`, `location`, or `scrolled` vars have changed, but it should only scroll into view, if it hasn't done that before.